# Group value in range r

Tags: r

I have my table(input)

```
name   value
Rob    35
Helen  20
Sergey 16
Linn   40
Elena  23
Mary   40
```

And I want to count how many of my users is in custom range (0-20,21-30,>30)(output):

```
range  num
0-20   2
21-30  1
30-    3
```

THX! Sorry if this theme not new, but I can't find answer!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a full solution, including your sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(name=c("r", "h", "s", "l", "e", "m"), value=c(35,20,16,40,23,40))
# get categories
df$groups <- cut(df$value, breaks=c(0,21,30,Inf))

# calculate group counts:
table(cut(df$value, breaks=c(0,21,30,Inf)))
```

If Inf is a little too extreme, you can use `max(df$value)` instead.

Answer (score 9):

Using `dplyr`, you can create (`mutate`) a new column indicating in which interval the value belongs (using `cut`) and then use this column to group your values and count (`n()`) how many of them you have:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(cuts = cut(value, c(0, 20, 30, Inf))) %>% 
  group_by(cuts) %>% 
  summarize(n=n())

#     cuts     n
#     (fctr) (int)
# 1   (0,20]     2
# 2  (20,30]     1
# 3 (30,Inf]     3
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use

```
library(data.table)
setDT(input)[,.(num=.N) ,
  .(range=cut(value, breaks = c(0,20, 30, Inf), labels = c("0-20", "21-30", "30-")))]
```