# use cut in R so that unmatched intervals are included

Tags: r

I have a data set like this:

```
sum_col   city    scen    model   time_period   chill_season
110.02     NY      RCP_8   bcc     2076_2099     season_2085_2086
91.26      NY      RCP_8   bcc     2076_2099     season_2086_2087
91.05      NY      RCP_8   bcc     2076_2099     season_2087_2088
74.96      NY      RCP_8   bcc     2076_2099     season_2088_2089
77.97      NY      RCP_8   bcc     2076_2099     season_2089_2090
109.05     NY      RCP_8   bcc     2076_2099     season_2090_2091
```

I want to `cut` the `sum_col` column and count how many times, the values fall 
within each interval `bks = c(-300, seq(20, 75, 5), 300)`.

However, when I try the following:

```
result <- dt %>%
          mutate(thresh_range = cut(sum_col, breaks = bks)) %>%
          group_by(time_period, thresh_range, model, scen, city) %>%
          summarize(no_years = n_distinct(chill_season, na.rm = FALSE)) %>% 
          data.table()
```

my result looks like:

```
time_period   thresh_range  model   scen    city   no_years
  2076_2099      (70,75]      bcc   RCP_8     NY     1
  2076_2099     (75,300]      bcc   RCP_8     NY     5
```

So, the intervals that are less than `70`, e.g. `(20, 25), (25, 30)`, are
not created (because there is no row in data that falls within those intervals).

Is there anyway to tell the `cut`, to return zero for those intervals?

Please note, again, that a row similar to the following:

```
 a_value_leass_than_70_here  NY   RCP_8  bcc 2076_2099  chill_2076_2077
```

whose corresponding `sum_col` is less than 70 does not exist in the data, however, I was wondering if it is possible for such a non-existing data, `cut` can create a `0` or `NA` that tells us the temperature of NY, with those parameters indeed did not fall in `(20, 25)` interval.

The bottom line is that I want to see how many years, each city with a given set of parameters `(model, scen, etc)` falls within each interval, `(20, 25), (25,30), etc.`,

If any suggestion other that `cut` works, that is great as well.

Comment: `Inf` and `-inf` can be included in the cut points. For example, check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37161547/group-value-in-range-r/37161796#37161796.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `complete` function from the `tidyr` package to create `NA` rows for missing combinations of data:

```
library(tidyr)
result <- dt %>%
          mutate(thresh_range = cut(sum_col, breaks = bks)) %>%
          complete(time_period, thresh_range, model, scen, city) %>%
          group_by(time_period, thresh_range, model, scen, city) %>%
          summarize(no_years = n_distinct(chill_season, na.rm = TRUE)) 
result
# # A tibble: 13 x 6
# # Groups:   time_period, thresh_range, model, scen [?]
#    time_period thresh_range model scen  city  no_years
#    <chr>       <fct>        <chr> <chr> <chr>    <int>
#  1 2076_2099   (-300,20]    bcc   RCP_8 NY           0
#  2 2076_2099   (20,25]      bcc   RCP_8 NY           0
#  3 2076_2099   (25,30]      bcc   RCP_8 NY           0
#  4 2076_2099   (30,35]      bcc   RCP_8 NY           0
#  5 2076_2099   (35,40]      bcc   RCP_8 NY           0
#  6 2076_2099   (40,45]      bcc   RCP_8 NY           0
#  7 2076_2099   (45,50]      bcc   RCP_8 NY           0
#  8 2076_2099   (50,55]      bcc   RCP_8 NY           0
#  9 2076_2099   (55,60]      bcc   RCP_8 NY           0
# 10 2076_2099   (60,65]      bcc   RCP_8 NY           0
# 11 2076_2099   (65,70]      bcc   RCP_8 NY           0
# 12 2076_2099   (70,75]      bcc   RCP_8 NY           1
# 13 2076_2099   (75,300]     bcc   RCP_8 NY           5
```